# How to calculate LED light output

Tags: visible-light, light-emitting-diodes

I'm trying to assemble an array of LEDs to be configured as a solar simulator. I need to compare this array's output to the solar spectrum as a function of W/m^2/nm.

To do this I need to go through datasheets of LEDs on sites such as Farnell, Digikey, etc. I am having trouble figuring out how to convert the units given in datasheets.

For example, if I have an LED that states typical lv (cd) @ 150 mA = 4.2, and Phi-v @ 150 mA = 12, at 120 viewing angle and 625 nm, how would I find out the W/m^2/nm? An arbitrary distance of 10 cm is set.

Datasheet of above example: http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1776464.pdf

Comment: This is a difficult problem in general.  First,  notice the 'relative intensity vs. wavelength' graph, which does give you the W/nm curve. The angular spread is shown in other graphs. But this LED is nowhere near solar spectral coverage -- you'll need either some "white" LEDs or a barrage of LEDs at different color lines.  (remember candela is a unit related to the eye-response, not actual power levels)